# Long list of Python errors when trying to install airbnb airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Getting this long list of errors, unable to figure out the root case of the issue

```
Found existing installation: python-dateutil 1.5
Uninstalling python-dateutil-1.5:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-uBZoOZ/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil'")]
```

Just trying to install airflow https://airflow.apache.org/ using

```
sudo pip install apache-airflow
```

Comment: The problem is that some versions of Apple's pre-installed Python come with an older version of `dateutil` pre-installed in their special `Extras` directory, and `pip` doesn't know how to install things to shadow packages in `Extras`.

Comment: While it's _possible_ to work around the `Extras` thing, it's a pain, and it changes every couple versions of macOS. Is it possible that you could (a) use Python 3.7 instead of 2.7, or (b) use a virtualenv instead of installing thing into the system site-packages, or (c) use a separate Python 2.7 (from python.org, Anaconda, Homebrew, etc.) instead of the system one? All of those would make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for the root cause analysis. I should be able to install Python 3.7 and try. If that doesn't work, will let you know!

Comment: Cool. I notice from [the `apache-airflow` PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/) that it only claims to support 2.7 and 3.4, but almost all code that works with 3.4 will also work with 3.7, so you shouldn't have to worry about that. (There are a few projects that do things like naming a variable `async` or `await`, which was legal but deprecated and is now illegal, but that isn't that common.)

Comment: So I installed python 3.7 and it seems like in OSX, it keeps the python executable as 2.x whereas the new executable is run under python3? I still get the same error while trying to install airflow.

Comment: Yes, until at least 2020, Unix (including macOS) installs of Python 3 are supposed to be run as `python3`. And that also means you want `pip3`, not `pip`. And depending on how you installed it, you probably don't need (and therefore shouldn't use) `sudo`.